# C++ Builder: Refresh FireMonkey Visual Component

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey

I have a problem with C++ Builder and FireMonkey. I am creating a mobile application connected with a Datasnap Rest WebService. Some requests are a little bit long so I want to display a waiting message. Here is my code:

```
lbl_testConnexion->Text = "Please Wait...";
lbl_testConnexion->TextSettings->FontColor = TAlphaColorRec::Red;
this->Invalidate();

//Call to the Web Service
list<Colis>* l = WS->getListeColis("00DP0097");

lbl_testConnexion->Text = "Success!";
```

I tried functions Form->Invalidate() and Label->Repaint() but only the last text is displayed.
What can I do to dynamically refresh the Label in my function?

Comment: now I don't really know about this builder or firemonkey but usually c++ is fast enough so your eye can't see the change in UI are you sure your query is running long enough like ~5s at least?

Comment: The query takes between 3 and 6 seconds so I'm sure it's not an optical effect. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of the text has to be handled by the main thread which is blocked by the request. If you don't want to use a seperate thread for long requests you have to call `Application->ProcessMessages()`.

```
lbl_testConnexion->Text = "Please Wait...";
lbl_testConnexion->TextSettings->FontColor = TAlphaColorRec::Red;
Application->ProcessMessages();

//Call to the Web Service
list<Colis>* l = WS->getListeColis("00DP0097");

lbl_testConnexion->Text = "Success!";
```

**Note:**

You have to be carefull with `Application->ProcessMessages()`. You can find many articles and discussions about this in the internet. When you work with the VCL there exists the method `Update` for controls of Type `TWinControl` which calls the function `UpdateWindow` of the WinAPI. Firemonkey does have a similar function, but only for Windows.

Include `FMX.Platform.Win.hpp` and replace `Application->ProcessMessages()` with `UpdateWindow(Platform::Win::WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle)->Wnd)`

Comment: STAY AWAY FROM `Application->ProcessMessages()`! If you just want the UI to repaint, use the `Repaint()` method of the individual controls, or even the Form itself, to process pending paint operations. Use the `InvalidateRect()` method to signal controls that need to be repainted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I tried this, too. But the control doesn't get repainted immediately. Also `TForm` doesn't have the method `Repaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an 'FMX dirty trick':

```
TabbedForm->Width = xxx + 1;
TabbedForm->Width = xxx;
```