# Updating visual components in android embarcadero c++builder

Tags: android, c++builder

I need to update several visual components in my app during a timeconsuming function, instead my app seems to hang during this function call, rather than update the visual components on the screen. When the function exit, I see only the last changes to the components.

Is there a simple way to do the updates, or do I need to create a parallel process and have a 'timer' to read the data simultaniously (using semaphores) and present them in the timer call ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you call Application->ProcessMessages() during your work?

Comment: Actually... no, didn't think about that. Will check it out!! Thnx!!

Comment: STAY AWAY FROM `Application->ProcessMessages()`! If you just want the UI to repaint, use the `Repaint()` method of the individual controls, or even the Form itself, to process pending paint operations. Use the `InvalidateRect()` method to signal controls that need to be repainted.

Comment: Will this work for Android as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219255/c-builder-refresh-firemonkey-visual-component). Like mh taqia said you can use Application->ProcessMessages() but you have to be careful with it. For my application, it worked but look at some posts about the function first.

Comment: I'll check it out ! Thnx alot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried following:

`MainForm->Invalidate();
MyControlRoot->Repaint();`

MyControlRoot is a control containing somewhat 50-60 different other controls

But MyControlRoot wouldn't repaint with this method. ..

Despite the warnings from you Remy, I tried `Application->ProcessMessages();`
...works for now...

By the way... I cannot see any warnings in [Docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages) on using ProcessMessages... what could I expect?

RG